# Youtube видео под дизайн сайта

Tags: html, youtube, css

Добрый день!

Кто нибудь знает, как можно поменять стили вставляемого видео?
К примеру, поменять "Большой красный PLAY" или вообще как это можно поменять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут небольшой конструктор от Гугла есть: [сцылко](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=ru)

UPD: и [вот](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube&hl=ru#resize_player) тут еще. Это всё из документированных функций.

UPD2: если совсем извратиться, то можно написать парсер (аля [savefrom.net](http://savefrom.net)), который будет вытаскивать линк к соурсу, и полученый линк скармливать любому опенсорсному плееру. Правда не знаю как к этому отнесется Гугл, если узнает :)

Comment: Эт конечно все круто, взял на заметку на будущее,но немного не то,мне нужно изменить стили встраиваемого плеера. )

Comment: Говорю же из документированных возможностей это всё. Остается либо предложенный мной вариант со сторонним плеером, либо лезть в недокументированные возможности, что не очень хорошо и может в любой момент перестать работать. А вообще нужно понимать, что youtube плеер представляет из себя флеш объект, и если разработчик не откроет возможность изменять интерфейс, то вряд ли у Вас что-то получится.

Comment: Не задача с этим iframe.
Окей спасибо и на этом. :D

Comment: Там кстати, не только как iframe можно использовать, по второй ссылочке, там с помощью js можно вставить object и передать ему параметры.

Comment: Надо попробовать .