# Как добавить видео на сайт со своей кнопкой запуска?

Tags: html, online-video

[image: Видео]

Здравствуйте, хочу добавить на html сайт своё видео с этой оранжевой кнопкой запуска, также чтобы была возможно увеличить на весь экран видео или при открытии занимало 80% экрана, а по краям был чёрный фон с прозрачностью. Может кто-нибудь может подсказать решение?

Comment: Похожий вопрос был задан [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132580/youtube-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0).